# 502 Bad Gateway Docker Symfony Nginx

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose

I have a problem with my docker configuration, my home page on localhost return always 502 Bad Gateway.

Here you can see the architecture of the projet :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfc24.png

the four container running :
https://ibb.co/XpQvnXj

I can access to phpmyadmin :
https://ibb.co/FXLqg8B

But when I go to the nginx port I have this issue :
https://ibb.co/2vs72jF

And this is the contents of the files.

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:

  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ../symfony:/var/www

  nginx:
    container_name: "nginx"
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../symfony:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs:/var/log
    depends_on:
      - php
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

php/Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:8.0.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev;

RUN curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- && \
   mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd opcache intl zip calendar dom mbstring zip gd xsl
RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

WORKDIR /var/www
CMD composer install ;  php-fpm
EXPOSE 9000
```

nginx/Dockerfile :

```
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD ["nginx"]
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx/nginx.conf :

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  4;
daemon off;


error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    upstream phpserver {
        server php:9000;
    }

    server {
        
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass phpserver;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            proxy_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_buffers 4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

error.log :

```
2021/10/13 13:53:04 [error] 25#25: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.16.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.16.3:9000", host: "localhost:8081"
2021/10/13 13:53:04 [error] 25#25: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.16.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.16.3:9000", host: "localhost:8081", referrer: "http://localhost:8081/"
```

I'm new to Docker so the problem is probably obvious

Comment: Can you extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, obviously, have you checked for other services running on those ports and perhaps interfering? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The four container running : 
https://ibb.co/XpQvnXj
 I can go on phpmyadmin localhost like this : 
https://ibb.co/FXLqg8B
But with nginx :
https://ibb.co/2vs72jF

Comment: Can you post logs from the nginx container?

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin I posted the error.log

Comment: Can you replace `fastcgi_pass phpserver;` with `fastcgi_pass php:9000;`?

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin it's done.
I have the same error 502 and the same log in error.log

Comment: Please put all relevant info into the question, you can [edit] it. Please do remove all irrelevant info though, so it becomes a [mcve]!